# Can you bring a standard tube of toothpaste on a plane in a carry-on bag?

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, hand-luggage, tsa

In the US, the TSA has very specific regulations for what can and can't be brought on a plane in a carry-on bag, especially when it comes to liquids. Can a standard tube of toothpaste be brought on a plane, or does it exceed the limitations? If it is too large, would a half-empty tube be accepted?

What about travel outside the US? Is toothpaste generally allowed on planes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "standard tube"? Is this a US-measure very much like the whole gallon-over-litre thing? I've used toothpaste tubes ranging volumes from 25ml to 100ml.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe "standard" tubes of toothpaste are about 6 ounces or more.  This would not be allowed within the US as TSA regulations limit liquids and gels to containers of at most 3.4 oz (100 ml).  Larger containers which are partially empty are specifically forbidden.  See http://www.tsa.gov/311/311-carry-ons.shtm.

Comment: I have found anything in a tube as well as anything that is a past, gel, jam, or jelly gets counted as a liquid regardless of weather it is or not.

Comment: @Stuart: according to the policy, they are *supposed* to be treated as liquids. The policy applies to "liquids, gels, aerosols, creams and pastes"

Comment: Your link is broken, but you are correct. I had a tube that had a tiny bit of paste left, it was folded right to a tiny bit at the end. TSA unrolled it pointed at "6oz" and tossed it in the trash.

Answer (score 5):

There are many toothpastes on the market with package sizing below the 100ml limit:

[image]

Make sure to buy one before you leave and you won't have any issues at the airport. Source: traveling with toothpaste on numerous flights.